# how do i capture the latest comment in a string after a specifc word?

Tags: python

I am trying to format the data in  string variable below to print the latest comment after the word "Patchset lock",i gave te expected output below,can anyone suggest how to fix it?

```
string = '''Patch Set 1:

This change is being verified in bugsfor the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:



=====================================================================================

git-android.comp.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml

=====================================================================================

https://commander.company.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  o https://review-android.comp.com/#change,



Please note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.

PLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.

Patch Set 1: Verified

Successful bugsverification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:

https://commander.company.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513

Patch Set 2: Failed

Failed bugsverification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:

https://commander.company.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217523'''



    '''
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
Failed bugsverification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:

https://commander.company.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217523"

'''
```

Comment: How to fix *what*? Have you tried code already? (Also, I don't see the words "patchset lock" anywhere in the text")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean (and your first code has `IndentationError`, by the way), but this might do the work:

```
>>> print(string.rsplit('Patch Set ', 1)[1].split('\n', 1)[1])

Failed bugsverification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:

https://commander.company.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217523
```

Explanation: `.rsplit('Patch Set ', 1)[1]` splits at the last occurence of `Patch Set` ([`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.rsplit)) and gets the second part (`[1]`), and `.split('\n', 1)[1]` splits at the first occurence of `\n` ([`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.split)) and gets the second par (`[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit tricky.

Basicly:

- Search for last String Position of `"Patch Set "`
- Make a Substring, from this position to end
- Search for second Position `\n`;
- Again, make a Substring, from this position to end

Don't know the functions in Python, but this should basicly do it.